# Load time for hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm a novice. How to improve the load time for hive for 5GB of data? Typically how long does it take to process 5GB of data in hive using multi node cluster? I'm using a single node cluster. Pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that by "load time for Hive" you mean you have local data that you want to load into a Hive table? I suspect that this process would be slower in a multi-node cluster than a single-node setup. This is because the data will likely be transferred to a different node in the multi-node cluster.

If you really need to speed things up in a multi-node environment you can always split your input data up, put each subset locally on different nodes, and load each partition concurrently into a HDFS staging area. A `hdfs dfs -mv` command can then move data very quickly into the Hive warehouse.

Comment: thanks ben! What about quering speed in say a three node cluster using hive for 1GB data? How will it take?

Comment: No problem. Query speeds would depend on the power of the nodes in the cluster, network speeds, storage medium and the complexity of the query - a cross join is going to take a lot longer than a `SELECT *` for example. It really shouldn't take long (minutes maybe), but I'd advise getting your own benchmarks based on your environment.